# Opengl es loads texture but now everything is that texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am now able to load a texture to the project I have made but it gave me results that I was not expecting.  Instead of loading my 91 tiles and having them have crate textures, and having a picture of a puppy be at 10x and 10 y, everything is the puppy.

This is my draw code

```
    @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
       gl.glLoadIdentity();         
       for(int i =0;i<91;i++)
      {
              myfloortiles[i].draw(gl);
      }
       gl.glLoadIdentity();  
       gl.glOrthof(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
       gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      // gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       gl.glTranslatef(10, 10, 1);
       bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.puppy);
       int textureID;
       int[] temp = new int[1]; 
       gl.glGenTextures(1, temp, 0); 
       textureID = temp[0]; 
       gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); 
       gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
       GL10.GL_NEAREST); 
       gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
       GL10.GL_NEAREST); // GL_LINEAR for quality. 
       gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
       GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
       gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
       GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
       GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); 
       bitmap.recycle(); 


}
```

Of course I have to be doing something wrong.  Is it that I have to make a 3d object and then render the texture to it?  Or is there another way?  Also how would I have an animation if i chose the 3d object with texture path?  Would I swap in new images when I want it to draw a different image for the interface?  Is my place the image in a specific location logic correct?  Or is that also terribly incorrect also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically not a mistake, but a problem is generating texture names and creating a texture object in the drawing function. Texture creating is a one-time thing:

- You generate a texture name, which is a handle by which you refer to the texture later (*glGenTextures*)
- You bind that name (*glBindTexture*)
- You upload the image (*glTexImage* and/or *glTexSubImage*)

For drawing the actual textured meshes you

- enable texturing (*glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_…)*)
- bind the texture(s) (*glBindTexture*)
- draw the mesh(es)

In your code you're going through the whole texture creation phase for every redraw. The last created texture is also the bound texture and thus will be subsequently applied to the following drawing calls. Which are about to happen in the next call of *onDrawFrame*

---

On a side note: You clearly have not understood how the matrix stack works. You mixed calls of *glOrtho, glLoadIdentity, glTranslate* and so on without any sensible structure. You need to get the understanding of those straigt, too. I'd say even before you tackle texturing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will now look at opengl.org on their faq for the matrix stack and how it works.